# How to represent a square wave in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have to represent a square wave in Matlab with amplitude 0.19 and period 495 samples and I don't know how to do. I have to do this because I have to estimate the function P(z) in the figure. I know the input w (is a vector with 5000 elements), I know r (another vector with length 5000), and I know that n(t) is this square wave, so I have to represent it in order to obtain the output of P(z) as r(t)-n(t). Can someone help me please?

[image: [figure]]

I just know that in Matlab there is the command `x=square(t)` that considers period 2pi, and I really don't know how to change it in order to represent my period and my amplitude. For the amplitude I just have to multiply the value for `square(t)` maybe?

Answer (score 0):

This little script might give you the fundamentals to use the `square()` function appropriately. The variable `Square_Wave_Frequency` will be the main factor controlling the frequency of your wave. The variable `Sampling_Period` will control the resolution of your wave, due to the discrete nature of MATLAB/digital computers. To adjust the amplitude simply multiply the signal returned by the `square()` function by the `0.19` required.

[image: Square Wave]

```
Start_Time = 0;
End_Time = 0.05;
Sampling_Period = 0.0001;
t = (Start_Time:Sampling_Period:End_Time);

Amplitude = 0.19;
Square_Wave_Frequency = 495; %Frequency in Hz%
Duty_Cycle_Percentage = 50; %ON half the time and OFF half the time%
Square_Wave = Amplitude*square(2*pi*Square_Wave_Frequency*t,Duty_Cycle_Percentage);

plot(t,Square_Wave);
title("Bipolar Square Wave " + num2str(Square_Wave_Frequency) + "Hz");
xlabel("t"); ylabel("Amplitude");
```

Comment: The only thing is... what I put for the frequency? Isn't the frequency the inverse of period?

Comment: It is. What's the period of your signal? Make sure not to mix it up with `Sampling_Period` is another independent quantity.

Comment: The text says "period 495 samples" so I should put frequency=1/495?

Comment: Do you mean there's 495 samples taken per period? If 495 samples are taken per period the `Sampling_Period = 1/495`. What is the wave expected to look like? If it oscillates between ON/OFF 495 times each second then yes,`Square_Wave_Frequency = 1/495`.